# Why is ubuntu a character?

Tags: css, unicode

Look at what this simple code produces:

[image: UbuntuCharacter]

Does this depends on the OS? (I'm using Linux Mint).

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sergioFC/a87zn6dg/)

`<div>Hola</div>`

`div:before {
    content:"\f200";
}`

Note: I was using ionic framework when I discovered it, but there is no need to include any library in order to see the character.

Comment: On Mac OS X I do not get the 'ubuntu' char. I only get a box.

Comment: This most certainly depends on the font family used ... more precisely if the font used has that particular character defined i.e. your fiddle example displays an undefined character on Mac OS X.

Comment: It depends on string encoding. I see box in Windows FF, Times New Roman font is used in JSFiddle.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/144379/ubuntu-logo-into-unicode-table

Comment: Thanks @Eric. If you want, provide the link as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is already answered on another stackexchange site, [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144379/ubuntu-logo-into-unicode-table)

In short, it's a character because that section of unicode space is free for private use, and the designer of the ubuntu font decided this is something they should do.